# Jquery Mobile .load() not retrieving content from Application Cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an application that uses cache.manifest to cache HTML content locally. When I retrieve this content using Jquery .load(), the content is NOT retrieved from the application cache and the call fails if the device is offline.

The files specified in cache.manifest are being loaded, I can see that in charles when I load in the site.

When offline I can enter the cached file URL in the browser and it shows it just fine, just not using .load(), so I am sure that the cache.manifest is loading everything correctly.

My question is, how can I load the HTML pages using jquery or plain JS, and make sure it uses the application cache if the device is offline?

```
CACHE MANIFEST
/m2/docs/e5a133db912860d8ec124cce9caa78d1/Q00X03.htm
/m2/docs/e5a133db912860d8ec124cce9caa78d1/M00X03.htm
/m2/docs/e5a133db912860d8ec124cce9caa78d1/Q97X01.htm
/m2/docs/e5a133db912860d8ec124cce9caa78d1/M97X01.htm
/m2/style.css
/m2/docs/e5a133db912860d8ec124cce9caa78d1/index.htm
/m2/docs/e5a133db912860d8ec124cce9caa78d1/doc.json
```

Then calling like this:

```
$("#docu").load("/m2/docs/e5a133db912860d8ec124cce9caa78d1/M97X01.htm");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This can't be THAT obscure. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working doing this (rather messy):

In my application I made a hidden iFrame:

```
<div style="display:none;">         
<iframe id="dummyContent"></iframe>
</div>
```

Setup a listener for this iFrame to read out the BODY and insert it into my display element anytime it loads:

```
$("#dummyContent").load(function(){
    var $con = $("#dummyContent").contents().find("body");
    $("#docu").html($con);  // docu is my display div
});
```

Set a click handler for the content retrieval button to set the src of the iFrame to my content: 
**THIS is loaded from Application Cache as expected.**

> ```
> $("#questionButton").click(function(ev) {
>      $("#dummyContent").attr("src","/m2/docs/e5a133db912860d8ec124cce9caa78d1/M97X01.htm");
> });
> ```

I would appreciate it if anyone had a different method, perhaps not using an iFrame. This solution is right up there with using tables to align page content...